# How to create a DAX measure that extracts Information from the metadata of Tabular model in SSAS or Power BI.?

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, ssas, dax, ssas-tabular

I have just started learning the SQL Server and Power BI. I'm working on a project and for that i need to create a Measure for the Power BI report that will dynamically extracts the information about all the tables (like Table Name, Last Updated, Dependencies, etc) used in the Tabular solution.

I couldn't find any satisfactory answer anywhere. Is there anyone here who could help?

Comment: I don't think DAX works on a meta-level like that. Can you explain your usecase?

Comment: Sorry I'm not very much familiar with these sql terminologies yet. So basically, I've a Tabular model and there are around 30 tables involved in the solution. So i'm trying to create a measure that extract the information about the tables from the metadata. So i could put that information in final report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using an SSAS tabular data model or multi-dimensional cube, you can use [DMVs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/instances/use-dynamic-management-views-dmvs-to-monitor-analysis-services) to extract meta data to report on or analyze.

This [ARTICLE](https://datasavvy.me/2017/09/19/the-tabular-model-documenter-is-now-a-power-bi-template/) includes a great walk through and a power bi template you can use to report on metadata.

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 1):

DAX isn't going to do this for you. However, there are 3rd party tools like [Power BI Helper](https://radacad.com/power-bi-helper) that will allow you to extract model details.